# Paste email subject & body into my iPhone app

Tags: iphone, copy-paste, email

I would like users to be able to paste a whole email into my App via a single copy operation. The default iPhone email app just seems to copy the body-text of the email (to be expected I suppose).

Does anyone know if the email app places the from: to: subject: and body: text into another more specialized PasteBoard during a user copy request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it doesn't.

With a jailbreak app, you could hook MobileMail and make it do that, however.

Comment: Ok thanks. After posting I realized that additional PasteBoard coping of say an email's CC list could lead the user open to opportunistic address theft by a rouge app raiding the PastBoard. I'll will mark this as this answer in another 24 hours if the thread does not develop further.